# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Al iniciar Android

Tags: android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al iniciar Android Studio, me sale éste error como se muestra en la imágen. Alguien que pueda ayudarme

Gracias.

Comment: al parecer el firewall de su pc esta bloqueando el puerto, intenta descativandolo temporalemente desde el menu inicio de windows-->buscar --> "firewall" -->dentro de ello selecciona la opcion deshabilitar firewall de windows. una vez que lo descartives intenta ejecutar el proceso que estabas realizando, luego de terminar vuelve a activar el firewall por seguridad.

Comment: Hola Wilson, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero revisar la sección de [ask], para que tu preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad. Es muy importante mostrar un [mcve]